# How can I make this plot in R? xlim and Date issue

Tags: r, date, plot, cumsum

First of all, I would like to thank you for your attention. Here it's my problem:

I have a dataframe, this is it's structure (I have deleted some rows):

```
DATE          PRODUCT      ORIGIN
11/03/2013      FV         Turkey
11/03/2013      BMPT       Turkey
12/03/2013      FV        Hong Kong
12/03/2013      HAS        Spain
12/03/2013      NNPS       Turkey
13/03/2013      MAMP       Poland
13/03/2013      PDAS       Italy
13/03/2013      FV         Tunisia
13/03/2013      FV         Turkey
13/03/2013      PMPMP      Belgium
14/03/2013      MAMP       France
14/03/2013      MAMP       Poland
14/03/2013      MAMP       France
15/03/2013      NNPS       United Kingdom
```

I would like to make a plot similar to this:
[image]

For this I execute this code in R:

```
cs<-cumsum(table(dataset$DATE))
plot(cs,type="l",col="blue",ylab="Number of cases")
```

The thing is that I would like that dates appear on the xlim instead of that "Index". I checked what cumsum does:

```
11/03/2013 12/03/2013 13/03/2013 14/03/2013 15/03/2013 18/03/2013 19/03/2013 
    11         18         30         43         59         80         96 
20/03/2013 21/03/2013 22/03/2013 25/03/2013 26/03/2013 27/03/2013 
   108        116        132        146        160        164
```

Number of cases: 164 (Cumulative) 11/03/2013 -> 11, 12/03/2013-> 7 and so on

I tried this:

```
axis(1, at=1:length(unique(dataset$DATE)), labels=unique(dataset$DATE))
```

But I got this, and I still see the "Index":
[image]

Is there any way to make a cumulative plot with Dates on xlim?

I hope you understand this question. If not, let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried including `xaxt='n'` in the call to `plot`? By default, plot puts an axis on the bottom and left sides, so you have to tell it that you don't want the auto-axis, otherwise you'll get overlap. (See `help(par)` and search for `xaxt` for more info.)

Comment: I think I got it, thank you! And thank you Henrik for editing my post, I could not show any picture because of the reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
plot(cs, type = "l", xaxt = "n", col = "blue", ylab = "Number of cases", xlab = "Date")
axis(1, at = seq_along(cs), labels = names(cs))
```

[image]

Comment: I've just checked it and it works. Thanks Henrik and r2evans!